# Python link to Google sheets not working, runs correctly yet does not create a token

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm trying to link a google sheet to python and have followed step by step instructions into how to do it. i have my credential set properly and have it all in the correct folders, yet when i run the code, it finishes yet nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

SPREADSHEET_ID = "1jtMnItUbOSE4tW-reymD4HPXoV7SxcDUC_qF54J3cM8"


def main():
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())

    try:
        service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
        sheets = service.spreadsheets()

        result = sheets.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet1!A1:C6").execute()

        values = result.get("values", [])

        for row in values:
            print(row)

    except HttpError as error:
        print(error)

if __name__ == "__main":
    main()
```

this returns "Process finished with exit code 0" and should return a list of the random item i put in google sheets